# How can I block Windows system functions, triggered by pressing, 'Windows Key' + F13-F24?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, corsair

I'm using a [Corsair Scimitar RGB Elite](https://www.corsair.com/us/en/p/gaming-mouse/ch-9304211-na/scimitar-rgb-elite-optical-moba-mmo-gaming-mouse-ch-9304211-na) mouse with its accompanying Corsair iCUE software v.4.33.138. Thumb grid buttons 1-12 are assigned to F13-F24 using iCUE.

Within **Windows 10 1809**, certain mouse key combinations trigger unwanted actions:

- Windows key + F16 = slide to shutdown
- Windows key + F17 = some wacky minimization thing
- Windows key + F20 = mini screen clipper
- Windows key + F21 = opens the settings
- Windows key + F22 = projector menu

I want to **block** these from happening.

I've tried:

- AHK (AutoHotkey) v. 1.1.33.02

  ```
  #F16::return
  ```

  ```
  <#F16::return
  >#F16::return
  ```

  - This code does **NOT** block 'Windows Key + F16' from triggering the system function listed above.

  ```
  #NoEnv
  #Warn
  SendMode Input
  SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%

  #InstallKeybdHook
  #Persistent
  KeyHistory

  #SC067::
  #SC067 Up::
  MsgBox, %A_ThisHotkey% was pressed.
  return
  ```

  - Using SC (scan codes) to target the key yields no use either. This example shows SC067, which represents F16.
  - To see the KeyHistory of the script directly above, after pressing 'Windows key + F16', see [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/U6g7VDBy).
- Disabling Corsair iCUE

  - Only if you use hardware assignments to the mouse using iCUE, will the thumb grid buttons continue to work when the software isn't running. The problem here is, F13-F24 aren't assignable to the hardware, they require the software, in order to be mapped to the mouse.
  - It's possible to remap 1-+, F1-12, or Numpad 1-Numpad+ to F13-F24, but this defeats the purpose of using F13-F24, as the purpose what to have a decoupled set of 12 keys that could be bound to the mouse. Remapping the other sets, either ruins their original functionality or adds complexity by requiring a state toggle using AHK.
- SharpKeys
- Key Remapper
- Key Manager
- KeyTweak
- Simple Disable Key
- X-Mouse Button Control
- Editing the DisabledKeys registry value to include F16. This is a Google Bard hallucination.

⚠ Microsoft PowerToys is a no-go. It requires Windows 10 v2004 (19041) or newer, a prerequisite I cannot meet. Installation attempts fail because of this reason.

**Any solutions for blocking these unwanted functions? I'm trying to preserve F13-F24, but not trigger the unwanted functions when these keys are paired with the Windows key.**

Comment: Have you tried Windows PowerToys?  Otherwise I don't know and they are not causing issues here.

Comment: None of those shortcuts are listed on the Microsoft website [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec) and I wasn’t able to reproduce the behavior of F14 by using SHIFT+Win+F2 which is F14 mind you.

Comment: @Ramhound F14 doesn't have any system functions for me. The other differences could be a difference in OS version. I have Windows 10 1809.

Comment: Your version of Windows 10 is out of support. Try updating to 22H2

Comment: Sorry, my point, none of those keyboard shortcuts are listed nor did they do anything on my system.  I originally counted to 16 but my brain failed me and I typed F14 for some reason

Comment: You have an out of date system, so hard to assist. If Power Toys do not help you, you may be just out of luck.

Comment: AHK should have been able to do that. Please add your AHK script to your post.

Comment: @harrymc I thought so too. I added the code. Multiple people in the AHK Discord have told me that AHK cannot stop these system functions.

Comment: @Psyntax - They are not system functions.  As they are not default system keyboards shortcuts, they are being provided by the software, or perhaps because it is a laptop by OEM (Dell, HP, etc.) drivers. I do assume that F21 is (Shift+F9)? So WinKey+Shift+F9 should replicate the behavior you witnessed with F21?

Comment: @Ramhound I'm going to ask Corsair support considering it's my Corsair mouse that is triggering these unwanted actions. My keyboard does not trigger these actions.

Comment: @Psyntax - Have you considered uninstalling the Corsair software? Without the software, the mouse cannot perform those unwanted actions. The fact you had a Corsair mouse and the relevant software installed should be included in your question.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that these keys combinations generate
[Special Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys),
so AHK cannot trap them with the usual selector of `#F16`.

To find out :

- Create and run the following `.ahk` script :

  ```
  #InstallKeybdHook
  #Persistent
  KeyHistory
  ```
- Right-click its icon and select Open
- Go to *View > Key historv and script info*
- Enter Winkey+F16 and then refresh with F5
- See what comes up in the history list, especially under the SC column
- If you see there a code like for example `159`, it could
  be intercepted with a rule like:

  ```
  SC159:: ; Replace 159 with your key's value.
  MsgBox, %A_ThisHotkey% was pressed.
  return
  ```

Comment: I tried this, including '#' to represent either Windows key. It read like #SC067::return. It does target the key, just like #F16, but cannot stop the underlying action. I'm following the lead that it's coming from the iCUE software that drives my mouse, which is the device these actions are being triggered from.

Comment: Are you using the [keyboard hook](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/_InstallKeybdHook.htm)?

Comment: yes, I updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: SC067 is undoubtedly F16. Could you include in your the entire key history when pressing Win+F16 ?

Comment: I included a raw Pastebin link of the key history generated by the script. Here it is: https://pastebin.com/raw/U6g7VDBy

Comment: Strange, it seems as if the LWIN key is repeating itself. Try to add a rule for `#SC067 Up::`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146169/discussion-between-psyntax-and-harrymc).